# Is there a way in Pandas to modify previous rows based on a certain row value?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe where something happens on every fifth row. I would like to represent column A below as a countdown before the 'x' on every fifth trial. Is there a simple code I could run that finds every 'x' and then numbers the rows after them 1-4?

Currently:

```
index A  
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   x
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  x
```

Desired output:

```
index A 
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   x
6   1
7   2
8   3
9   4
10  x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to look at it based on the position of the row within the actual DataFrame, you can reframe the problem to be related to modular arithmetic. You're looking to count the trials with mod 5 arithmetic. You can use a statement like the following, which will label which number the trial is and will give every 5th trial an `'x'` as its value:

```
df["A"] = df.index.map(lambda x: 'x' if x%5 == 0 else x%5)
```